# Why the method "getIcon" in class "ShellFolder" in jdk17 always returns null?

Tags: java

The version of the jdk is AmazonCoretto-17. I want to get the system icon of file.

I find that I can use the method "FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getFileIcon(File)" to solve the problem, but the returned value is always null. I check the source code of the method, then I find that the method invokes the another method called "getIcon()" in the class "ShellFolder". As I check the source code of the latter, I find that the method always returns null. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Depending on your OS, a sub class of `ShellFolder` is used. For instance, on Windows class `sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2` extends `ShellFolder` to actually implement icons.

Comment: The only other sub class I could find on GitHub is `sun.awt.shell.DefaultShellFolder` which doesn't override the icon methods, so I guess this only works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve the problem?

I assume that you are trying to use `getSystemIcon` not `getFileIcon`.  (The latter doesn't exist!)

And I assume that you are trying to use it on a non-Windows platform.  Unfortunately `getSystemIcon` on a non-Windows system will only give you a generic file or directory?

Why?  Because that is all that they have implemented in the OpenJDK codebase!

But **why**?  My *guess* is ... because there is no single standard way to get file type icons on generic Linux & Linux platforms.  To illustrate, review the answers to this:

- [How do you get the icon, MIME type, and application associated with a file in the Linux Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629172)

A Linux / Unix implementation in OpenJDK would need to interact with many different native window managers, each of which handle this issue differently.  It would be a lot of work for the Java team to implement and maintain compatibility with a cat-herd of window managers.

While Oracle / OpenJDK Java are committed to supporting AWT + Swing as part of the Java platform, they don't appear to be investing many resources in enhancing them.  You could say that HTML 5 and Android have won.

Comment: Generally, Swing considers Gnome the ’official’ environment on Linux.  The system look & feel is com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel.  So, I would go with the XDG specification for Linux.

Comment: Yea ... but your typical Linux user doesn't like to be told what window manager to use.  ("You are takin' away my freeeeedom")